# How to disable textarea and keep caret active

Tags: html, textarea, caret

I was wondering how you would be able to accomplish the scenario where you have a disabled textarea and at the same time you want to have the caret of the text cursor still active, Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to disable, you may be looking for the `readonly` attribute. This prevents pasting or typing, but not selecting and copying. It also doesn't grey out the element.

```html
<textarea>This is a normal textarea.</textarea>
<br>
<textarea readonly>This is a readonly textarea.</textarea>
<br>
<textarea disabled>This is a disabled textarea.</textarea>
```

Now if you *do* want to grey out the element, so that it has the `disabled` look, you can set its colours using CSS.

```css
textarea[readonly] {
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, .15);
  border-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, .15);
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<textarea>This is a normal textarea.</textarea>
<br>
<textarea readonly>This is a readonly textarea.</textarea>
<br>
<textarea disabled>This is a disabled textarea.</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What i really need is a real read-only textarea while maintaining the caret in it so that users are able to position the caret in the desired place of the text, at the same time, user is not allowed to modify the text.

Comment: Interesting. I see now that Chrome doesn't show a caret, while the other browsers do. This is probably a problem with Chrome and I'm not sure there's a simple solution.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that this is on google chrome only, your answer works for other browsers and hence it got accepted, Thanks.